# Channel.read returns -2

Tags: java, sockets, stream, nio

I'm using Java NIO to do socket operations.  In the past when working with streams, the `read` call (where you are reading into a byte array, or in this case a `ByteBuffer`) returns the number of bytes read from the stream, or -1 if the stream was closed.  So you basically can do

```
while(channel.read(buffer) != -1){
  //do stuff
}
```

However, I noticed that I was killing my servers.  When I added some logging statements, I noticed that the `read()` call was returning -2 at the end of the stream.  According to the documentation:

> *Returns: The number of bytes read, possibly zero, or -1 if the channel
>   has reached end-of-stream*

Has anybody experienced this before? I changed my code to loop on a value >0, but I wanted to make sure I understand what's going on.

Comment: This may be specific to the JDK implementation on a particular platform, and/or may be specific to which type of Channel you're using. You might specify those. (I don't know the answer either way though.)

Comment: What is the class of the channel object you are reading?  What does "System.err.println(channel.getClass())" say?

Comment: With that code how can you tell what it returns?